# Initialize variables with names from a file

Tags: matlab

I have a txt file with a bunch of parameters created by the external program.

Let us consider a simple example:

input.txt

```
a= 1
b= 2
c= 3
```

I can read both names and values in matlab 2018a:

```
[names, values]=textread('input.txt','%s%f');
```

As a result, names will be a 3x1 cell array with entries `a=`, `b=` and so on, whereas values will be a conventional `3x1` array of doubles.

In my current workspace, I want to initialize the obtained variables (with the corresponding names) and set them equal to the corresponding values.
In the example above, variables `a=1`, `b=2` and `c=3` should be created in the current workspace.

I have no idea how to do it...

Thanks!

Edit: in my actual example variable names can contain many characters/numbers (by the standard convention, variable names always start with the letter, not a digit), e.g.

```
Rcirc1= 30.0
SaveStride= 1000
```

Comment: If you can change the extension of the input file from `.txt` to `.m`, it will automatically become a `script` so you can simply call it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of [regexp](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) and [assignin](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/assignin.html) to achieve the desired output:

```
%Read data.
data = fileread('input.txt')

%Extract variable name and value in named groups.
s = regexp(data,'(?<var>[A-Z]\w+)\D+(?<val>\d+(?:\.\d+)?)','names');

%Loop over struct s contents to create variables in workspace.
cellfun(@(x,y) assignin('base',x,str2double(y)),{s.var},{s.val})
```

Comment: well, it does not work exactly (may be because I have names that consists of several letters), but thanks for the starting point

Comment: You should update your OP with that information. I will be happy to adapt the answer for that situation. The first part of the regex would simply change from `(?<var>[a-z])` to `(?<var>[a-z]+)`.

Comment: You are welcome. I've updated my answer, let me know if that helps.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 2):

The assignments in the text file can be directly evaluated by MATLAB. You don't need to extract them. In order to silence the text printed for each line you can use `evalc`

```
evalc(fileread('input.txt'));
```